# Angularjs is undefined when try import to webpack bundle

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I try import `AngularJS 1.6.5` to my app.
I use `webpack 3.7.1` as module bundler.
Also, I use `typescript` for transpile my code.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack_test_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "angular": "1.6.5"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './views/resources/js/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'] 
    }
};
```

app.ts

```
import angular  from './node_modules/angular/angular.js';

console.log('angular is -> ', angular);
```

After all chrome console print `angular is ->  undefined`

Also I tried  `import angular  from './node_modules/angular/angular';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to include all dependencies.

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Typings

to do 
Step1: execute command to install tsd

```
npm install -g tsd
```

Step3: execute command to install typings

```
tsd install angular
tsd install angular-route
```

then in app.ts

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

Comment: if you need more info 
https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide/tree/master/typescript